# How to install ffmpeg on linux using ssh or putty

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, php

I am trying to install ffmpeg on my server (Linux) but could not succeed.

i tried this command in the putty

> sudo apt-get install ffmpeg

then restarted apache. Still i dint find ffmpeg in phpinfo.php

Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the php5-ffmpeg-package:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-ffmpeg
```

.